# Javascript to deny image saving

Tags: javascript

I need a working script for prohibiting users from saving images on their machine. (Is it only possible through disabling right-click?)
Yes, I know that it is impossible, and yes I know that it is a bad practice.
Yes, I also know that I am an idiot. But I need this solution for some specific purposes.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not going to be easy. Modern browsers like Chrome & Firefox allow users to simply drag images right off the browser onto the desktop or file manager window. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Once your web server has delivered an image to the client browser, it's out of your control. Even if it couldn't be saved by right-click or dragging off, the user could take a screenshot of it and crop out the window around it.

Comment: @Michael: You can prevent drag n drop by setting it [as a background image](http://jsfiddle.net/Dv6Fu/). You're right about it ultimately being impossible to prevent, but it seems that OP knows that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to replace all the `<img>` elements with `<div>` elements that have the same size and use the image as a background:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var $img = $(this);
    var $div = $('<div>').css({
        width:           $img.width(),
        height:          $img.height(),
        backgroundImage: 'url(' + $img.attr('src') + ')',
        display:         'inline-block'
    });
    $img.after($div).remove();
});
```

I'm using jQuery because DOM manipulation like this is a bit of a nightmare in raw JavaScript (and because this isn't a free code writing service). This won't stop anyone but it will keep them from dragging the images off your page or doing a "Save As..." from the context menu. This sort of thing also won't do anything if your users disable JavaScript.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4Hca3/

I'll leave translating this to whatever JavaScript libraries (if any) you're using as an exercise for the reader.

You can try disabling the context menu but not all browsers (such as Firefox) will pay attention to that sort of chicanery.

Comment: This looks like it suits best my needs. I would really appreciate if somebody can submit the same version of the code in pure javascript

Comment: @user194076: As I said, DOM manipulation in raw JavaScript is a nightmare so today I am not someone :) OTOH, now that you know what you're looking for, your googling might be more successful.

Answer (score 2):

the only real way to do it is probably to encrypt the images in a flash file or something, but no matter how much time you spend jumping through hoops the user can still just press printscreen.  there is no reason to even try doing this.

Answer (score 0):

http://javascript.about.com/library/blnoright.htm

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

Or...

```
document.body.oncontextmenu = function(){
    return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EEMsm/

Comment: Natively? I don't think the OP is looking for a durable/in all cases unbreakable script...

Comment: I don't remember if I've adjusted the configuration to force this sane behavior. I haven't adjusted the configuration any time in the past couple years but I have been dragging around my Firefox configuration for quite some time.

Comment: Well, it works in my FF4 - you may have NoScript or something else. Anybody with Firebug or who can save the page can get the images. The OP admitted as much in the question. This type of thing amounts to low-hanging fruit, in other words. I agree, I think it's silly, but this is a completely relevant answer to the question.

Comment: I think I must have flipped one of the internal flags manually at some point. I only have a couple developer tools installed in my Firefox. The real problem (IMHO) with disabling the context menu is that it contains a lot of useful things other than "save as" and that won't stop someone from simply dragging the image off the page.

Comment: Oh yeah, it's probably not a great idea (;)), but hey, sometimes you need something to temporarily fool someone. Even if it's just some creative agency flack checking something off a checklist. If someone decides to use it, buyer beware.

Answer (score 0):

One non-js way to make it harder for people is to absolutely position and size a clear png/gif on top of anything you want to make hard to download with a right click. When they try to save the image, they'll just get the clear one.

EDIT

I just saw this question which is related

[How does Flickr prevent people from downloading images from the site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129404/how-does-flickr-prevent-people-from-downloading-images-from-the-site)